# Does a solution exist to Diophantine Equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I'm interested in finding if an integer solution exists to the equation $ax^2 + bx + cy + d = 0$

I found Dario Alpern's website https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM which has a solver that seems to determine if a solution exists by trying to solve an equation of that form using module 9, 16, and 25. For example, $x^2 + 5 x + 15 y + 50 = 0$ gives "No solutions found using mod 9, so there are no integer solutions." but $x^2 + 15 x + 5 y + 50 = 0$ gives "There are solutions, so we must continue.".

My question is: how does module 9, 16, and 25 allow us to know if a solution exists and where can I find more information? Internet search didn't lead me anywhere - probably because I'm not using the right keywords.

To be clear, I am not interested in actually finding solutions; only whether or not a solution exists.

Comment: To use more familiar notation, I'm referring to the general form $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$ with $b=c=0$, leaving $ax^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$ (although I relabeled the final coefficients in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+5x+15y+50\equiv x^2+14x+15y+50=(x+7)^2+1+15y\bmod9$. Now $15y$ is a multiple of 3, but $u^2+1$ isn't, so there is no solution modulo 3, never mind modulo 9.

In general, for your type of equation, $ax^2+dx+ey+f=0$, it makes sense to work modulo $e$: $ax^2+dx+f\equiv0\bmod e$. Completing the square on the left side, you will wind up with a congruence of the form $z^2\equiv g\bmod e$, so all you have to do is work out whether $g$ is a quadratic residue (that is, a "square") modulo $e$, and any intro Number Theory text will tell you how to do that, using quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: That is true if $a$ and $e$ are coprime, and $e$ is odd or $d$ is even.  Otherwise it can be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How is $x^2 + 5x +15y + 50 \equiv x^2 + 14x + 15y + 50$? The $5x$ to $14x$ is not clear to me. If we can always substitute $f = m + n$ and get to a form $(x + \sqrt{m})^2 + n \equiv 0 mod e$ and work $mod e$, why does it matter if $a$ and $e$ are coprime and what can we do if they are not?

Comment: mod $e$, not mode

Comment: Did you miss the "mod 9", Dio? $5\equiv14\bmod9$. I encourage you to make up an example where $\gcd(a,e)\ne1$, and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry Gerry, I overlooked the mod $9$. That makes sense. With your help I'm beginning to see that $f(x) \equiv 1$ mod $e$ is the best way to determine if a solution exists (or use $gcd(a,e)$ to make $a,e$ coprime) and the quadratic residue is an excellent source of information.I would venture to guess that the website's statement about using mod 9, 16, and 25 is a coding error, rather than a method to checking if a solution exists.

Comment: Please let me know if I've misunderstood something otherwise I will accept your reply as answering the question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't think using 9, 16, and 25 is an error. Think about the problem of deciding whether a given integer is prime. You might first see whether it's divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7, ..., 97, say. If it is, you're done – the number isn't prime. If it's not divisible by any of those, you don't know whether it's prime, but you haven't wasted much time, since those divisibility tests are very fast, especially compared to the more sophisticated tests for primality. With the Diophantine equation, similarly, testing modulo 9, 16, 25 may work, and doesn't waste much time if it fails.